# Update SQL database with using statement and SqlParameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

I'm just starting out to learn all about sql databases. For now based on previous suggestions that was given to me online, I've incorporated a using statement to avoid problems in sql connection and then I applied parameterized queries to avoid sql injection. I was also been given an advice to use sqlparameter arrays to supplement the parameterized queries that i implemented. I just want to know if there are other techniques that you would recommend to improve my code, which i will indicate below. Feel free to suggest better solutions.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["brandsConnection"].ToString())) {
    string query = "UPDATE [guitarBrands] SET type = @type, name = @name, image = @image WHERE id = @id";
    SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[4];
    p[0] = new SqlParameter("@type", newType.Text);
    p[1] = new SqlParameter("@name", newName.Text);
    p[2] = new SqlParameter("@image", newImage.Text);
    p[3] = new SqlParameter("@id", id);

    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        GetExample(command, p);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}

public void GetExample(SqlCommand command, params SqlParameter[] p)
{
  if (p != null && p.Any()){
        command.Parameters.AddRange(p);
   }

}
```

Comment: Instead of writing ADO.NET code, learn to use an ORM like [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723.aspx). As Jeremy Miller said: ["if you’re writing ADO.Net code by hand, you’re stealing from your employer or client. "](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/11/07/how-to-design-your-data-connectivity-strategy/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Stacking the `using` statements

I am particularly difficult to please with code that has nesting, and I highly prefer to stack the `usings` when it is possible.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = ...)
{
    using (SqlCommand command = ...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

versus

```
using (SqlConnection connection = ...)
using (SqlCommand command = ...)
{
   ...
}
```

### Exception Handling

You should include exception handling into your code, as it will likely throw an exception sooner or later (such as getting disconnected, network issues, etc.)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = ...)
using (SqlCommand command = ...)
{
    try
    {
        // open the connection, execute, etc
    }
    catch
    {
        // log and handle exception(s)
    }
}
```

### Using Lists not Arrays

It would likely do you more harm than good to be using an array, especially in the context of maintainable code. I would recommend you switch to using Lists, like this:

```
List<SqlParameter> p = new List<SqlParameter>();
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@type", newType.Text));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", newName.Text));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@image", newImage.Text));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
```

This will let you introduce more items into your parameters without having to do deal with the headaches of explicitly indexing.

*Note: If you want to keep the same method signature for your* `GetExample()` *method, then don't forget to pass the parameters as an array --- you could use* `ToArray()` *to accomplish that.*

---

Here it all is together...

```
string query = "UPDATE [guitarBrands] SET type = @type, name = @name, image = @image WHERE id = @id";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["brandsConnection"].ToString()))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
{
    try
    {
        // open the connection, execute, etc
        List<SqlParameter> p = new List<SqlParameter>();
        p.Add(new SqlParameter("@type", newType.Text));
        p.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", newName.Text));
        p.Add(new SqlParameter("@image", newImage.Text));
        p.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

        connection.Open();
        GetExample(command, p.ToArray());
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
    catch
    {
        // log and handle exception(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: Fail.  Use query before it is defined

Comment: @Svek - thank you for the brand new technique.